# Does flashplugin still use mms.cfg?

Tags: adobe-flash, iceweasel

I was poking around the flashplugin of Adobe for Linux trying to get the Hardware Acceleration working (which my current configuration supports). Then I found several forums/blogs that recommend I create/modify some or other value in the `/etc/adobe/mms.cfg`, which didn't help at all for my current situation.

This leads me to think, does the Flash non-free plugin of Adobe for Linux read this file for configuration? Is there another way to modify Flash configuration without the traditional GUI's (`flash-player-properties` doesn't help in the HWA topic and I am already tired of ticking the box Right-click -> Settings -> Enable Hardware Acceleration)?

I'm using Iceweasel 24.0a2, Debian Wheezy 7.0, *Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202 11,2,202,297*.

```
$ glxinfo | grep render
direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on ATI RV515
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These settings are found in settings.sol, buried deep in the profile directory `~/.macromedia/` The problem is that this file is a hex file. I got a [sol editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/soleditor/) off the internet, but only works on windows.

When I had to turn off Hardware Acceleration, I had to check the `safefullscreen` setting in the sol editor. It disabled hardware acceleration. I think that if you unselect it it will enable the Hardware acceleration again.

Comment: I would love a native linux editor. But indeed the file is there, just that I can't read it since all editors are made for windows (and wine is not an option).

Comment: I completely  I looked for a while and although there are hex editors for Linux there are no sol editors

Comment: If you manually set the .sol file once you could write a profile.d script to copy it to,the right location if it isn't the right one  that's what I,did at work